# Как вывести число с полной точностью?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Читаю учебник Лутча по Питону 2011-го года издания и в нём описана такая ситуация: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что когда я эти операции ввожу у себя, то при обоих способах число выводится в форме str. Как полностью отобразить число?

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, слова Лутца устарели.
Как видно - repr работает по другому.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако суть вещей не изменилась и можна вывести "правду" при помощи форматирования вывода, как показано выше

Answer (score 2):

Ну и я тоже докину вариант) Можно использовать встроенные модуль `decimal`, с помощью которого можно осуществлять вычисления с очень большой "точностью"

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal(3.1415 * 2)
print(x)             #  6.28300000000000036237679523765109479427337646484375
# можно преобразовать к строке и "обрезать" до нужной длины
print(Decimal(str(x)[:18]))   #  6.2830000000000003
```

Comment: Основной плюс `Decimal` в том, что он десятичный (как и следует из названия), а не двоичный, и всех этих `...0003623767...` (артефактов округления до ближайшей двоичной дроби) вообще не будет при правильном использовании `Decimal('3.1415') * 2`

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
a = 3.1415 * 2
n = 16 // количество знаков после запятой
template = '{:.' + str(n) + 'f}'
print(template.format(a))
```

Результат:

```
6.2830000000000004
```